# Any reason this query should recklessly delete rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We have a SQL script that gets run every so often to delete orphan records in our DB..

```
Delete From [factFooDetail]
Where [FooHeaderID] Not In (Select [FooHeaderID] From [factFooHeader])
```

For some reason a bunch of records that had header id's in the header table appear to be deleted regardless!

We are running SQL Server 2005

Are there any rare bugs / edge cases in which this would not work as expected?

Comment: Have you verified that this statement indeed is the reason for the missing rows?

Comment: Are you sure that the detail rows were added in the first place?

Comment: Yep, the rows were definitely added.. we don't know for sure if that query deleted the rows but that is the only automated process that messes with that table. The other (more likely) explanation is human error, but nobody's owned up so i thought i'd better check its not some edge case bug before we release the hounds! :)

Comment: Your current query would delete rows where FooHeaderID is null otherwise it should not touch the rows with a proper FooHeaderId from [factFooHeader]. You can often select the rows first before deleting to avoid these situations. I assume you have a backup.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: then the WHERE is always false = no deletes

Comment: Why do you have orphan records? Why not a (possibly cascading) FK? In any event the query looks fine I would assume human error. You might be able to determine some information about when they were deleted from `sys.fn_dblog` if the transaction log still contains that data.

Comment: @gbn you are right, those rows would not delete. My bad

Comment: In your cleanup script, why don't you dump the records that are going to be deleted into a table -- *factFooDetail_Deleted*. Then you can determine if the script is responsible for the problem.

Comment: What data type is FooHeaderID? Are they defined the same in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

The query seems to be fine. However, it is difficult to tell without seeing the real query as it might have additional clauses (`where`, `group by`, etc) that might affect the result returned by the subquery and hence, the deleted rows.

For example, if you filter just 1 record from the subquery and there is a record that corresponds to it in the detail, then all detail rows for the filtered header record will be deleted.

Take that into account and make sure you're not filtering additional rows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually see the rows deleted directly after running this statement?

Try and replicate the issue with the exact parameters/values that would have been called in production.

Don't rule out the possibility that someone manually deleted the data, or some other code deleted the row.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any rare bugs / edge cases in which this would not work as expected?

It depends on the value for `ANSI_NULLS`, but as best I can tell this will only cause it to delete the data you expect, or less.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;

CREATE TABLE #factFooHeader
(
  FooHeaderID INT
);

CREATE TABLE #factFooDetail
(
  FooHeaderID INT
);

INSERT INTO #factFooDetail
VALUES (1), (2);

INSERT INTO #factFooHeader
VALUES (1), (NULL);

DELETE FROM #factFooDetail
WHERE FooHeaderID NOT IN (
    SELECT FooHeaderID FROM #factFooHeader
);

DROP TABLE #factFooDetail;

DROP TABLE #factFooHeader;
```

Yields the following result:

```
(2 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
```

However, with `ANSI_NULLS` set to `OFF`:

```
(2 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

If you have multiple predicates in your `WHERE` clause then the behaviour could be made even more confusing, since the [Three-Valued-Logic Truth Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:3VL_Truth_Table.png) no longer holds with `ANSI_NULLS` set to `OFF`.

Comment: Can't explain the behaviour in the OP. To begin with `FooHeaderID` is probably the PK of `factFooHeader` and not nullable but even if we assume it does contain `NULL` the worst that will happen is that no rows will be deleted when `ANSI_NULLS` is on. There are no circumstances in which it will delete arbitrary additional rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith My answer is directed at the question I quoted.